# How to change the state of the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, use-state

I am creating a simple application using react and I have two components: Form and Modal. The Modal should be opened when the Form is submitted. How to change the state of the Modal component to achieve this ?

This is the code for the Form.js compent:

```
import Modal from './Modal'

export default function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <SuccessModal />
      <div className='mt-1'>
        ...
    </form>
)}
```

This is the code for the Modal.js compent:

```
export default function Modal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as='div'
        static
        open={open}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
     </Transition.Root>
```

I tried to pass this state as a property, but I think I'm doing something wrong. I would be very grateful if any of you could explain to me the principle of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have modal state in **Form.js** and then pass the state as props to **Modal.js**.

On Form submit set the modal state.

Form.js

```
import Modal from './Modal'

export default function Form() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
    setOpen(true);
  }
  return (
   <>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <SuccessModal />
      <div className='mt-1'>
        ...
    </form>
    {open && <Modal open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />}
    </>
)}
```

Modal.js

```
export default function Modal({ open, setOpen }) {

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as='div'
        static
        open={open}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
     </Transition.Root>
```

Comment: Simplest most strait forward implementation

Comment: Thank you for the solution. There was only one syntax error. There was a missing `/` at the end of the Modal component :)
It should be:  `{open && <Modal open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />}`

Answer (score 2):

the state controller `useState` should be in the parent, not the `Modal`.

Then you can simply use a prop to define the `open` state.

One way we do this at my work is creating a custom hook for it:

```
// stateless modal component
export default function Modal({ open }) {
  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as='div'
        static
        open={open}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
     </Transition.Root>
}

// custom hook
export function useModal({ initialState }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(initialState)

  return {
    component: <Modal open={open} />,
    setOpen,
  }
}

// parent code
import { useModal } from './Modal'

export default function Form() {
  const modal = useModal(false)
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    modal.setOpen(true)
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {modal.component}
      <div className='mt-1'>
        ...
    </form>
)}
```

Comment: Nice use of custom hook

Answer (score 1):

You can try lifting the state of the child (Modal) to the state of the parent (Form). [Refer this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use state for show or hide Modal component. Use the props. With props components will be working like this:

```js
import Modal from './Modal'

interface IFormProps {}
interface IFormState {
  isModalOpen: boolean
}

export class Form extends React.Component<IFormProps, IFormState> => {
  state: IFormState = {
    isModalOpen: false,
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e): void => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  const handleModalClose = (): boolean => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} handleClose={this.handleModalClose} />
      <div className='mt-1'>
        ...
    </form>
)}
```

```js
interface IModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean
  handleClose: () => boolean
}

interface IModalState {}

export class Modal extends React.Compnent<IModalProps, IModalState> {
  const { isOpen, handleClose } = this.props

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as='div'
        static
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
     </Transition.Root>
```